# How to add a new datarow to datatable in filtering cases

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with filter applied for one column.

```
DataTable dt=new DataTabe();
var datarow=dt.NewRow();
dt.Rows.Add(datarow);
```

But it doesn't add the new row on filtering cases.How can i fix this one

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: your datatable has no `columns`,

Comment: datatable has 8 columns and 12 rows -add new datarow i got 13 rows but applied filter, to filter the four values it has shown 8 rows after adding the new datarow